# How to bound or emphasise names?

Tags: apostrophe, names

I'd like to ask how to properly write names is US English text. To explain what I mean by names in my case, let's start by example:

> Now create two files. Name the first one for example X and the second one Y.

Those names are attributes of those files, not type of the file. Whenever anyone creates such file, he gives it any name he wants, like 'My great new file'. How to properly typeset them US english text? For now, I am using simple apostrophes, like

> Name the first one for example 'X' and the second one 'Y'.

Is that correct? Or should I use italics, monospace font, single quotes, double quotes or something else?

Note that English is not my primary language.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The presentation of written English is largely a matter of style; there is no single right or wrong way to indicate a use/mention distinction. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, to the [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) of your preference.